# Probability that n+X_n is increasing for an i.i.d. sequence

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have some i.i.d. sequence $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, and define $Y_n :=n+X_n$.  What is the probability that $Y_n$ is increasing from $n$ to $m$?

In more detail, we fix some $n<m \in \mathbb{N}$, and we want to know the probability:
$$\mathbb{P}\{\forall r \in\{n,\dots,m-1\}: Y_r  \leq Y_{r+1}\} =$$
$$\mathbb{P}\{\forall r \in\{n,\dots,m-1\}: X_r  \leq X_{r+1} +1\}$$
Now I'd like to use the independence to get an expression in function of $F_X(t) := \mathbb{P}\{X \leq t\}$ but this isn't possible yet as every $X_r, r \in \{n+1,\dots,m-2\}$ occurs twice.

Comment: It might help if you said what the distribution of $(X_n)$ was. If they're uniform on $[0,1]$, it seems that the probability is quite high.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas, if X is uniform on [0,1] then the probability here is 1.  So X standard normal is a better test case.

Comment: @MattF: Yes indeed. 1 is what I meant by quite high.

Comment: The X_n are just have an arbitrary distribution on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: My main interest here is to be able to rewrite the expression into a form which we can compute

Comment: I doubt you'll get a nice form for this. Incidentally, this reminds me slightly of something: if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are Unif[0,1] iid random variables, then $\mathbb P(X_1<\ldots<X_n)=1/n!$ since each of the $n!$ orderings of the variables is equally likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compute these probabilities symbolically for some distributions using Mathematica.  Letting $k=m-n$, the code is just

```
f[dist_, k_]    := Integrate[(f[dist, k-1] /. w->v) (f[dist, 1] /. u->v) PDF[dist,v],
                             {v, -Infinity, Infinity}]

f[dist_, 1]      = Boole[1 + w > u]

prob[dist_, k_] := Integrate[f[dist, k] PDF[dist, u] PDF[dist,w], 
                             {u, -Infinity, +Infinity}, {w, -Infinity, +Infinity}]

Table[prob[UniformDistribution[{-1, 1}], k], {k, 1, 3}]
Table[prob[ExponentialDistribution[1],   k], {k, 1, 3}]
Table[prob[NormalDistribution[],         k], {k, 1, 2}] //N
```

For the uniform distribution on [-1,1], the first three probabilities are $\frac{7}{8}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{41}{64}.$

For the exponential distribution with parameter 1, the first three probabilities are $\frac{2e-1}{2e}, \frac{6e^3-6e^2+1}{6e^3}, \frac{24e^6-36e^5+6e^4+8e^3-1}{24e^6}.$

For the standard normal distribution, the first three probabilities are 0.760, 0.536 and 0.369, but there were no nice closed forms.  For the third normal probability, there was no advantage to the symbolic manipulation, but Mathematica could do a more direct calculation numerically.

Comment: Actually, the first normal probability is F(1/sqrt(2)), but that wasn't immediately obvious to me or to Mathematica.

Comment: Nice, the more you know :)!